# Suspicious behaviour of users

Tags: discussion

Take a look at [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/regarding-the-units-of-the-shift-produced-by-subsidies-on-supply-curve).

It was answered 10 minutes after being asked, and accepted right after that  (a rather quick timing for this site, I believe). To me, speaks about premeditate coordination. Both users were created today, and they are both relatively similar, as both seem to speak Spanish, given their names and the nationality one declares. They could even be the same person.

My question is: is this something to be suspicious of? In particular, that the two users might ask questions and provide answers to each other, in order to increase their reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Current reputations of the users are at 8 and 16, so this does not seem to be the scam of the century. As long as this is not a systemic issue I don't think any action is necessary.

Comment: Of course if two users with high reputations would be doing this, it might be worth looking into. But I think they would probably do it in a less obvious way. For example if @KitsuneCavalry and I were secretly always upvoting each other's answers I think I would try to cover it up by always getting into bogus arguments in the comments.

Comment: Out of interest, what is normally done if this becomes an issue?

Comment: You can flag questions in need of moderator intervention. The moderators have broad tools including suspending accounts. Not sure what someone would gain by having fake 10k points though.

Comment: @denesp Of course, we never argue over anything :^). Now if *I* were trying to collude with denesp or we were secretly the same person, I'd try to distinguish ourselves by playing good cop bad cop, where one of us plays the hard nosed, sarcastic, jaded user, and the other plays the bright-eyed, aloof, well-meaning user who is a little too willing to help answer questions.

Comment: **b o t t o m t e x t**

Answer (score 1):

Certainly suspicious, not less because the one username is "diego**batt**" the other "Matias **Batt**occhio". Both contain the component "**Batt**". They could be relatives, or as the OP say they could be the same person using a "socket puppet" to vote up him/her self. Moreover, the "answer" is not answer, just a comment.

I would suggest that the moderators monitor the activity of these two users.
(cc @ubiquitous)

I am cc-ing both users, cc @diegobat, cc @Matias Battocchio